# PostgreSQL - How to use index for this kind of query

Tags: postgresql

We got this query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE A AND ( B = X1 OR B = X2 ) AND ( C = X3 OR D = TRUE ) AND E = 0;
```

I created this index:

```
CREATE INDEX _my_index ON public.table USING btree (A, B, C, D, E);
```

But I don't get any better performances ... how to deal with such queries for indexing ? 
Thank you !

Comment: Do you really need to select all columns in the table, and if not, then which columns do you need to select?

Comment: A index on a `boolean` column usually doesn't make sense unless the distribution of the true/false is in favor of one of the values (e.g. 10% true, 90% false). Typically a partial index is more helpful (`where a`). Given your conditions, I would put `B` as the first column in the index, and depending on the data distribution maybe `E` as the second. But it all depends on the distribution of the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that `X1`, `X2` and `X3` are constants and not table columns.

You won't be able to index `C = X3 OR D = TRUE` — `OR` is always a performance problem.

The condition `B = X1 OR B = X2` should be rewritten to `B IN (X1, X2)`.

Then this is the best index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON "table" (e, a, b);
```

If you *always* want to query for truth of `a` and `e = 0`, a partial index would be even better:

```
CREATE INDEX ON "table" (b) WHERE a AND e = 0;
```

If you need to index the conditions on `c` and `d` as well, and the table has a primary key, you can rewrite the query to:

```
SELECT * FROM "table"
WHERE a AND b IN (X1, X2) AND c = X3 AND e = 0
UNION
SELECT * FROM "table"
WHERE a AND b IN (X1, X2) AND d AND e = 0;
```

For this query, the following two indexes are commendable:

```
CREATE INDEX ON "table" (c, a, e, b);
CREATE INDEX ON "table" (e, a, d, b);
```

Again, you can move certain index columns into a `WHERE` condition if you always query for a certain value.

Comment: Thank you for your reply ! Is the order of the column in 

CREATE INDEX ON "table" (c, a, e, b);
CREATE INDEX ON "table" (e, a, d, b);

random or there is a specific reason ? ( Because it doesn't match the order of the columns in the UNION query ).

Comment: The order is random, the only important thing is that `b` is in the end. You can adjust the order so that the index is useful for other queries too.